# is posible to excute codebehind Event first while dropdown change

Tags: asp.net

I have code like

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SiteIDDropdownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SiteIDDropdownList_OnSelectedIndexChanged" onChange="javascript:markItUpApply();">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here I need fire first "OnSelectedIndexChanged" then "onChange"

is It possible?

Comment: please mark the answer that solved your problem as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the onchange attribute and register a startup script that will fire after the postback has completed which i think in effect will work just as you want.

In your OnSelectedIndexChanged Event you can use.

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "testScript", "markItUpApply();", true);
```

EDIT:

In case you have update panel in the page then use this code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "testScript", "markItUpApply();", true);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: I did whatever you point above.but markItUpApply() is not fire.

Answer (score 2):

"onChange" is a client side event whereas "OnSelectedIndexChanged" is a server side asp.net event, there is no way to fire these in a different order.

Try moving the code from onChanged into the OnSelectedIndexChanged event, of course you will need to convert it to .net code

Answer (score 0):

Well the case is that both are events and will fire when dropdown list onselected. But if you want to delay your codebehind call you can give this a try:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
```

But it will give you a delay for 2 sec and its not the best practices at all.